# What does this regex do?

Tags: php, regex

`^.+\\(.*\\)`

I am struggling to work this one out, any help would be greatly appreciated...

also is there a site that lets youu paste in a regular expression then spits out in plain text what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have already described it's components, so I'll give you some examples - allthough I'm not sure what `\\(` and `\\)` stands for. It depends on your regexp-engine. If they match literal parenthesis, this regexp will match the following strings:

```
abc(def)
abcdef()
```

but won't match these:

```
abc
(abc)
abc(def)ghi
(abc)def
```

In case they match literal slashes and open/close a group, your regexp will match:

```
abc\def\
```

Comment: Thanks that is a really good explanation... I will expect your answer

Answer (score 3):

> also is there a site that lets youu paste in a regular expression then spits out in plain text what it means?

For instance the [Regular Expression Analyzer](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html) gives this result for your regex `^.+\\(.*\\)`:

```
Sequence: match all of the followings in order
    BeginOfLine
    Repeat
        AnyCharacterExcept\n
        one or more times
    (
    Repeat
        AnyCharacterExcept\n
        zero or more times
    )
```

Comment: Damn nice tool. Didn't know that one

Answer (score 1):

- ^ is the start of line
- . is any (non-newline) character
- .+ is one or more of any (non-newline) character
- .* is zero or more of any (non-newline) character

Then, there are two possibilities for \\( and \\):

- \\ is a backslash, and ( opens a group.
- \\( is a literal opening parenthesis.

Comment: \\( is literal opening parenthesis. \\\( is \ followed by a group start

Answer (score 1):

```
^ text starts with
. any character
+ 1 or more instances
\\ \ character
( group start
* 0 or more characters
) group end
```

So.. The string starts with several any characters followed by \ followed by optinally several any characters followed by \

Answer (score 1):

`^` Start at the beginning of the string
`.+` Match one or more of any kind of character (except newline)
`\\` Literal backslash
`(` Start group
`.*` Zero or more of any kind of character (except newline)
  `\\` Literal backslash
`)` End group

After matching, the captured group will have a backslash and any number of characters after it.